# Screaming Frog reporting duplication between two canonicalized pages

Tags: seo, duplicate-content, title, rel-canonical, screaming-frog

I have Page-A with canonical pointing towards page B. Page B should be considered the original and should be ranked in SERPS.  But the Screaming Frog crawler is showing that page A and B are duplicating in term of their title and description. Why are canonicalized pages still be categorized by the crawler as duplicated in terms of h1, title and description etc?

One way to avoid the issue would be to use canonicalized + non-index (follow) but I believe it is not recommended. Why is it not recommended when it has more benefits like link value transferability, saving web's crawling budget and avoid duplication?

Comment: This post is asking two distinct questions: 1) Why does Screaming Frog act a certain way, and 2) From an SEO perspective, why is it not recommended to use canonical + noindex? I think it would make more organizational sense to ask these in separate posts. Both are good questions, though the answer to (1) would probably be to ask the developers.